# Display every 3rd record in table

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table which contains 30 rows I want to display every 3rd record in that table in the same order I'm using row_number but order changed .

```
Select * from (select *,rn=row_number() 
over(order by name)
from employee_030)x
where rn%5=0
```

It will get order by name,.
I want records without using order by clause.

Comment: Shouldn't it `rn%3=0` ?? why you using modular 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY (SELECT 0)` as follows

```
Select * from (select *,rn=row_number() 
over(ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
from employee_030)x
where rn%3=0
```